# How to get TypeScript to treat any given folder the same way it treats the 'types' folder?

Tags: typescript, declaration

So I wrote a bunch of declaration files for a global library under one namespace. I have over 50 `d.ts` files organized in various sub folders, all in the `types` folder. All of the files are written in this style:

```
declare namespace pc {
  class Foo {}
  function bar(): void;
}
```

I don't use any triple slash directives, exports or imports anywhere in my declaration files or in my project's source code. TypeScript just does its thing and everything works. Now lets say I wanted to move all of my declaration files to a different folder, say folder `node_modules/playcanvas-typings`, what do I need to do for TypeScript to use the declaration files from that folder the same way it uses the ones in the `types` folder?

I have tried adding the folder to `typeRoots` in `tsconfig.json` but it doesn't work. Here are the compiler options in my `tsconfig.json`:

```
"compilerOptions": {
  /* Basic Options */
  "target": "es5",                          
  "module": "commonjs",                     
  "lib": [                                  
    "es2017",      
    "dom"
  ],     
  "sourceMap": true,                        
  /* Strict Type-Checking Options */
  "strict": true,
  /* Module Resolution Options */
  "moduleResolution": "node",               
  "typeRoots": [   
    "node_modules/playcanvas-typings"
  ],    
  /* Experimental Options */
  "experimentalDecorators": true,           
  "emitDecoratorMetadata": true             
}
```

My IDE and the compiler are giving me `Cannot find namespace 'pc'` errors.

Comment: Just put it in `tsconfig.json`: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html#types-typeroots-and-types

Comment: @jonrsharpeI tried puting it `typeRoots` and it doesn't work.

Comment: Then give a [mcve] specifying what you've tried and what the outcome was (*"doesn't work"* isn't much for people to work on).

Comment: @jonrsharpe I have edited my question following your recommendations. Let me know if I need to add any other info and thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

include your folder in `tsconfig.json`

```
{
  ...
  "include": [
    "types"
  ]
}
```